# Anaconda cannot find OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I've installed OpenCV in Ubuntu through `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` and then `pip install python-opencv` in Anaconda, but if I try to import the cv2 module I get error:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo version of opencv?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install OpenCV in Anaconda, you must use 'conda' command in the terminal.

I have answered a similar question and you can follow this link below for detailed instruction on how to install it on Anaconda. Here is the link where I answered it:

[Installing opencv 3.1 with anaconda python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787748/installing-opencv-3-1-with-anaconda-python3/39240127#39240127)

This is command that I used to install it. Note that you must have an internet connection for this to work.

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

The above command will install the latest version of OpenCV which is 3.10.

I hope that helped you =)